# Connecting an Azure Webapp to an existing virtual network

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I would like to connect to a database server running inside an existing Azure Virtual Machine (Azure Resource Manager) which is connected to an existing Azure Virtual Network.

I've created a new Azure Webapp using settings for Subscription, Location and Resource-Group identical to the virtual network used by the Virtual Machine. Yet, when I try to connect the Webapp to the network from the Azure Preview Portal no existing Virtual Network is selectable. I only have the option to create a new one which is obviously not what I want.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can connect a webapp to a vnet, you have to enable "point to site" connectivity on your network and create a new gateway.